# Adding figures with a certain order

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to add some figures in a specific order as shown below but it didn't work, Any Ideas?

[image]
My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
     \centering
     \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{a.PNG}}
     \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{b.PNG}}
     \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{c.png}}
     \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{d.png}}
     \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{e.png}}
    \caption{main caption}
     \label{f1}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please add a minimal working code `\documentclass....\end{document}`

Comment: @touhami thanks for your comment, I updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
 \centering
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{example-image}}

 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =\linewidth]{example-image}}

 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
 \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width =.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
\caption{main caption}
 \label{f1}
\end{figure*} 

\end{document}
```

[image]